# Replace text with other text in file

Tags: regex, powershell

I have this line which does what its supposed to do:

```
Get-Content $OutFax\$newName |ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "a", "b" }| Set-Content $OutFax\$txtName
```

Opens a file and replaces a with b. 
But in the real world a is:

```
<ToFaxNum:11111111>
```

I would like to replace that with

```
::11111111
```

The ::11111111 could be any number between 1 and 9 and from 8 to 15 numbers. After ToFaxNum:11111111 there is a new line.

I have not tried anything because i have absolutely no idea how to solve it. I dont understand regex.

Thank you.

Comment: this is what you are looking for `ToFaxNum(:\d{8,15})` see demo https://regex101.com/r/kY6gR2/3

Comment: Thank you. The actual text that needs replacing does have <> around it.

Comment: then  this would work out fine `<ToFaxNum(:\d{8,15})>`. See the new demo https://regex101.com/r/kY6gR2/4

Comment: Do you mind if i post it as an answer

Comment: Please do, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work out fine

```
<ToFaxNum(:\d{8,15})>
```

Then replace the matched string with `:\1`

**EXPLANATION**

**`<ToFaxNum`**: matches less than sign `<` followed by `<ToFaxNum`

**`(:\d{8,15})`**: matches and captures a colon `:` followed by at least 8 digits and at most 15 digits

**`>`**: matches the greater than sign `>`

check out the  [demo](http://regex101.com/r/kY6gR2/4)

Answer (score 2):

The `-replace` operator supports *capturing*, just enclose your pattern in `()` in the first argument:

```
PS C:\> "<ToFaxNum:14435242624>" -replace '<ToFaxNum:(\d{8,15})>$','::$1'
::14435242624
```

`\d{8,15}` means between 8 and 15 consecutive digits. We can then refer to this *captured* group as `$1` in the second argument.